# Flutter, after upgrading to 3.10, "Future isn't a type"

Tags: flutter, dart

After upgrading flutter with `flutter upgrade` to 3.10

All my (previously working) Futures stopped working. Every single future is underlined with red saying "Future isn't a type".

What can I do to fix this? Clearly Future hasn't been removed.

Comment: Try running `flutter pub get` in terminal

Answer (score 4):

This was happing to me too after upgrade to 3.10.

I am using VS Code. After opening with Android Studio, I was able to build it without any problem.

Going back to VS Code, and it starts to work again.

Comment: you save my life, in my case i use `fvm` for version `3.10.6`

Answer (score 4):

Just reloading VsCode fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

add "import 'dart:async';" in your code and change "future" to "FutureOr"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Once you upgrade to **Flutter 3.10**, make sure you change the Flutter SDK environment version in **pubspec.yaml** file

Change From:

```
environment:
  sdk: 'existing_version'
```

To:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.3 <4.0.0' //TODO: Change Version
```

After this run,

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade
```

Answer (score -2):

Flutter clean
Flutter pub get

I think that will work for You

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunely